# How to generate a pop up with a selection prompt for which object to download when invoking the downloadHandler function in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, download, popup

In the below MWE code, the `downloadHandler` successfully allows the user to download the first plot "vector1" defined below in the function `vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector1_input())`. However, I'm trying to modify the below so that upon clicking the download button, the user is prompted via pop-up with a selection to download either vector1 or vector2, the latter defined below in function `vectorVariable(input$base_input[2,1],vector2_input())`.

Can someone please help me code a conditional pop-up with some sort of `selectInput` or analogous for download object, triggered by clicking the download button?

I'm trying to stick with native Shiny function `downloadHandler` because it does a very nice job of prompting the user with choices for download directory. I have found this very difficult to do outside of `downloadHandler`.

Note that in the full App this MWE is derived from, there are more than two PNG files to select for download. Also, in the full App that same download button is used in separate `server` sections not shown in this MWE for downloading data tables (which work well) --- so any changes for object download selection need to be done in the `server` section, leaving the `downloadButton("download", "Download")` in the `UI` section untouched since it handles more than just these PNG files shown in this MWE (I guess this means some sort of `renderUI`...).

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

matrix1.input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(x, 
              value = matrix(c(0.2), 2, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B"),NULL)),
              rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

matrix2.input <- function(x,y,z){
  matrixInput(x,
              value = matrix(c(y,z),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("Y","Z"))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}  

matrix.validate <- function(x,y){
  a <- y        
  a[,1][a[,1]>x] <- x 
  b <- diff(a[,1,drop=FALSE]) 
  b[b<=0] <- NA               
  b <- c(1,b)                 
  a <- cbind(a,b)
  a <- na.omit(a) 
  a <- a[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]         
  return(a)}

vector.base <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x) 
  b <- seq(1:x) 
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a) 
  return(c)}

vector.multi <- function(x,y,z){                                            
  a <- rep(NA, x)
  a[y] <- z       
  a[seq_len(min(y)-1)] <- a[min(y)] 
  if(max(y) < x){a[seq(max(y)+1, x, 1)] <- 0}   
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)],a[!is.na(a)],seq_along(a))$y  
  b <- seq(1:x)                                                     
  c <- data.frame(x = b, z = a)                                     
  return(c)}

vector.multiFinal <- function(x,y){
  vector.multi(x,matrix.validate(x,y)[,1],matrix.validate(x,y)[,2])}

matrix.link <- function(x,y){
  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,x,value=matrix(c(input$periods,y),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL, c("y","z"))))})}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput("Panels")),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Dynamic", value=2,
                 actionButton('showVectorPlotBtn','Vector plots'),
                 actionButton('showVectorValueBtn','Vector values'),
                 
                 downloadButton("download", "Download"),
                 
                 uiOutput("vectorTable")),
        id = "tabselected")
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  periods       <- reactive(input$periods)
  base_input    <- reactive(input$base_input)
  vector1_input <- reactive(input$vector1_input)
  vector2_input <- reactive(input$vector2_input)
  yld           <- reactiveValues()
  
  vectorVariable <- function(x,y){
    if(input$showVectorBtn == 0) vector.base(input$periods,x)
    else vector.multiFinal(input$periods,matrix.validate(input$periods,y))}
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==2",
        sliderInput('periods','',min=1,max=120,value=60),
        matrix1.input("base_input"),
        useShinyjs(),
        actionButton('showVectorBtn','Show'), 
        actionButton('hideVectorBtn','Hide'),
        actionButton('resetVectorBtn','Reset'),
        hidden(uiOutput("Vectors"))))})
  
  renderUI({
    matrix.link("vector1_input",input$base_input[1,1])
    matrix.link("vector2_input",input$base_input[2,1])})
  
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({input$resetVectorBtn
    tagList(matrix2.input("vector1_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),
            matrix2.input("vector2_input",input$periods,input$base_input[2,1]))})
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorBtn,{shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hideVectorBtn,{shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector1_input())))
  output$graph2 <- renderPlot(plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[2,1],vector2_input())))
  
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {paste("vector1","png",sep=".")},
    content = function(file){
      png(file)
      plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector1_input()))
      dev.off()}
  ) # close download handler
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({vectorsAll()})
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorPlotBtn,{yld$showme <- tagList(plotOutput("graph1"), plotOutput("graph2"))},ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  observeEvent(input$showVectorValueBtn,{yld$showme <- DTOutput("table1")})
  
  output$vectorTable <- renderUI({yld$showme})
  
  vectorsAll <- reactive({
    cbind(1:periods(),
          vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector1_input())[,2],
          vectorVariable(input$base_input[2,1],vector2_input())[,2])})})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to make the restriction of using only one `downloadButton`. I'd trigger a modal with an `actionButton`. On the modal UI I'd display a `selectInput` and a separate `downloadButton`.

Comment: Hi ismirsehregal, after giving it more thought I agree with your suggestion above. Plus I need to get more comfortable with using modalDialog as it's very useful for expanding my fields of inputs as my model grows. In a moment I'll answer the question with the working MWE that incorporates your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to the comment from ismirsehregal, below is the working MWE that uses an actionButton which triggers a modal with selectInput and download button inserted in said modal. This is a clean solution from ismirsehregal.

MWE code (omitting the libraries and functions definitions from the original MWE for the sake of brevity; if you want to run this MWE below, make sure to copy in the libraries and defined functions from above!!):

```
ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput("Panels")),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Dynamic", value=2,
                 actionButton('showVectorPlotBtn','Vector plots'),
                 actionButton('showVectorValueBtn','Vector values'),
                 
                 actionButton("showDownload", "Download"),
                 
                 uiOutput("vectorTable")),
        id = "tabselected")
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  periods       <- reactive(input$periods)
  base_input    <- reactive(input$base_input)
  vector1_input <- reactive(input$vector1_input)
  vector2_input <- reactive(input$vector2_input)
  yld           <- reactiveValues()
  
  vectorVariable <- function(x,y){
    if(input$showVectorBtn == 0) vector.base(input$periods,x)
    else vector.multiFinal(input$periods,matrix.validate(input$periods,y))}
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==2",
        sliderInput('periods','',min=1,max=120,value=60),
        matrix1.input("base_input"),
        useShinyjs(),
        actionButton('showVectorBtn','Show'), 
        actionButton('hideVectorBtn','Hide'),
        actionButton('resetVectorBtn','Reset'),
        hidden(uiOutput("Vectors"))))})
  
  renderUI({
    matrix.link("vector1_input",input$base_input[1,1])
    matrix.link("vector2_input",input$base_input[2,1])})
  
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({input$resetVectorBtn
    tagList(matrix2.input("vector1_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),
            matrix2.input("vector2_input",input$periods,input$base_input[2,1]))})
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorBtn,{shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hideVectorBtn,{shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector1_input())))
  output$graph2 <- renderPlot(plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[2,1],vector2_input())))
  
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
          if (input$downloadItem == "Vector1") {paste("Vector1","png",sep=".")}
          else {paste("Vector2","png",sep=".")}
      },
    content = function(file){
      png(file)
      if (input$downloadItem == "Vector1"){plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector1_input()))}
      else {plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[2,1],vector2_input()))}
      dev.off()}
  ) # close download handler
  
  observeEvent(input$showDownload,
               {showModal(modalDialog(
                   selectInput("downloadItem","Select item to download:",
                               c("Vector1","Vector2")),
                   downloadButton("download", "Download")
                 
                 ) # close modalDialog
                ) # close showModal
               } # close showModal function
  ) # close observeEvent
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({vectorsAll()})
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorPlotBtn,{yld$showme <- tagList(plotOutput("graph1"), plotOutput("graph2"))},ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  observeEvent(input$showVectorValueBtn,{yld$showme <- DTOutput("table1")})
  
  output$vectorTable <- renderUI({yld$showme})
  
  vectorsAll <- reactive({
    cbind(1:periods(),
          vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector1_input())[,2],
          vectorVariable(input$base_input[2,1],vector2_input())[,2])})})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```